# Caching and Session state management using Microsoft Velocity and Memcached

Tags: asp.net, memcached, appfabric

I was looking at Microsoft Velocity and memcached to find a solution for some session management issues -

What is the difference between caching that is provided by Microsoft Velocity, memcached and session state management? I mean memcached and microsoft veolocity provide distributed caching capabilities... so using these to store session state would mean that session state would also be distributed .. Am i right in this assumption

Answer (score 1):

The difference between caching an session state management is that caching is at the application level(caches data for all sessions).  Also cache can timeout many times during a session.  Use cache for holding frequently used information(i.e information from a lookup table).  This way your application wont have to access your data source unnecessarily.